# asp.net webrequest

Tags: asp.net, html

so i have this asp.net webform.  I have to send data remotely to another ccomputer, but the thing is the other computer is behind some corporal firewall so i cant use sockets or anything.  So my way of gettin around this is to write my data to a database on another server that i have access to , and then the other computer just constantly reads that database for new data, the problem is that is too slow.  ANy better approach? I was thinkin of using webrequest/webrespose but im not familiar with tht, if im to use that, how do i request the specific data that i want.  Becasue the asp.net webpage has buttons, when one button is click it sends out a diff data. how does the other computer request gets the right one when using webrequest/response

The asp.net webpage is the one that have to send data to the other computer which is behind firewall that i have no control over.

Answer (score 1):

If it's behind a firewall, and you can't use sockets, it's unlikely you're going to be able to talk to the box using a webrequest, unless someone opens the firewall to http traffic. If that is the case use WCF.

Your other option is to use Queues via SQL server service broker:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108(SQL.90).aspx